PostgreSQL physical and logical replication - key values
PostgreSQL.
When using physical replication, does a given row in a table in the replica database have the same primary key value as its corresponding row in the primary database?
Same question when using logical replication.
Thank you.

This site works best with single questions.  You can make it into a single question by saying "physical or logical".  Otherwise there is a possibility that the question could be closed.

Both Physical replication as well as logical replication the downstream server i.e, standby in case of physical replication and subscriber in logical replication will have the exact values as in the source. In logical replication a table is expected to have primary key for UPDATE
& DELETE operation but for physical replication a PK is not mandatory for such operations.
Additionally physical replication works on whole cluster while logical replication have selectivity which allows you to choose database/schema/tables.
